# SELECT with EXEC is possible in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need to write dynamic insert query, which must be in select statement. To be more specific I need a select statement, of insert query.
I will try to explain with an example

lets say we have the following table

```
create table employee
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    name varchar(100),
    gender bit
)
```

lets insert few records in it

```
insert into employee values ('John',1),('Chris',1),('Emily',0)
```

now I need query which outputs

```
insert into EmployeeBAckup (empid, empname, gender)
select (1,'John',1),(2,'Chris',1),(3.'Emily',0)

/*
insert into EmployeeBAckup (empid, empname, gender) --> its a static text
select (1,'John',1),(2,'Chris',1),(3.'Emily',0) --> Result of query
*/
```

things I have tried

```
    'insert into EmployeeBAckup (empid, empname, gender)' + EXEC ('SELECT * FROM employee')

    declare @q1 varchar(max) , @q2 varchar(max), @q varchar(max)
    set @q1 = 'insert into EmployeeBAckup (empid, empname, gender)'
    set @q2 = 'SELECT * FROM employee'
    set @q2 = EXEC(Q1+Q2)

    SELECT @Q1 +' '+EXEC(@Q2)
```

your help is much appriciated

Answer (score 1):

You can do 
 insert into tablea 
select * from tableb

Does tablea have an identity column? You cannot insert into an identity column unless you issue an 'set identity_insert 'table_name' on'

Why are you using an exec?

This works too:

```
set @str='select * from t2'
exec (@str)
insert into t
exec (@str)
```

where t and t2 have the same columns and column types.

If its static you can do this:

```
insert into t
select (1)
union
select (2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used EXEC coz ..
insert into EmployeeBAckup (empid, empname, gender) --> **its a static text**
select (1,'John',1),(2,'Chris',1),(3.'Emily',0) --> **Result of query**

Comment: You have never cast any votes. Its easy and you can encourage users to post answers.

Comment: benjamin moskovits I need to frame Insert Query and SELECT it

LIKE 
SELECT ('INSERT INTO T2 (COL1, COL2, COL3) ' + SELECT * FROM T1)